# Піщаний-пісковий-пісочний

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

В українській мові є слова піщаний і пісковий. Але пісочний також вживається, наприклад, стосовно тіста. Чи доречне таке вживання, якщо ні, то як сказати правильно?

Answer (score 4):

Відразу відповідь на ваше запитання:

Так, пісочний можна використовувати стосовно тіста.

Слова "**піщаний**" і "**пісковий**" є ближчими один до іншого синонімами (наприклад, і піщана, і піскова (але не пісочна) **пустеля**; піщаний **берег** і піскова **земля**), аніж ці два слова є синонімами до "**пісочний**", бо останнє - радше **поверхнева характеристика** чогось, аніж вказівник на те, що щось складається з піску (пісочне **печиво**, пісочна **оса** (колір) тощо).

Детальніше у [статті з "Як ми говоримо"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53407/31821.html) Антоненка-Давидовича:

> **Пісковий**.
>
> 1. Який стосується піску, складається з піску, містить у собі багато піску: піскові бархани, піскова пустеля, піскова земля,
>      піскова поверхня.
> 2. Який діє за допомогою пересипання піску: пісковий годинник.
>
> **Пісочний**.
>
> 1. Який стосується піску; для якого використовують пісок; кольору піску: пісочні ванни, пісочні оси, пісочне пальто.
> 2. **Крихкий, сипкий (про печиво, тісто): пісочний торт.**
> 3. **Те саме, що піщаний**
>
> **Піщаний**.
>
> 1. Який складається з піску: піщаний берег, піщана коса, піщаний пляж, піщана пустеля.
> 2. Який містить у собі багато піску: піщані грунти, піщана дорога, піщана буря.
> 3. Який живе, росте на піску, в пісках: піщана мітлиця, піщаний цмин, піщана акація.
> 4. **Те саме, що пісковий** 2: піщаний годинник.

Екскурс в історію:

1. У словниках Грінченка та Кримського (і ко) слова "пісочний" немає. Воно з’являється вже у радянському [СУМі](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), а потім - у новіших [рос-укр словниках](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) 2004 і 2009 років, а також в [укр-англ словнику](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) 1955 року. Я би сказав обережніше користуватися цим словом, але в [ґуґлі](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&lr=lang_uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK19a66d_ZAhXPy6QKHYEiD9AQpwUIHw&biw=1366&bih=662) знаходимо 106 тис результатів для цього слова на україномовних сторінках, тож можемо стверджувати, що слово повністю прижилося, ним можна користуватися без засторог.

Answer (score 0):

Всі три слова є в СУМі:

[Пісочний](http://sum.in.ua/s/pisochnyj):

> //  Для якого використовують пісок. На столі канделябр, розп'яття,
>   **пісочний годинник**, великі книги, папери (Іван Кочерга, I, 1956, 117); Пісочні ванни;
>
> //  Який живе або росте в піску, пісках. Пісочні оси;
>
> //  Кольору піску; сірувато-жовтий. Пісочне пальто.
>
> 2. Крихкий, розсипчастий (**про печиво, тісто**). Пісочне печення — крихке, розсипчасте у вигляді крендельків, батончиків, коржиків
>      (Українські страви, 1957, 335).

[Піщаний](http://sum.in.ua/s/pishhanyj) :

> 1. Який складається з піску. Правий бік Дніпра, скутий скелями і вкритий одвічним лісом, неначе біг до нас назустріч, а лівий,.. як
>      рута, зеленів, одмічаючись од блакитної річки піщаною полосою (Олекса
>      Стороженко, I, 1957, 245); «Там, певно, добре купатися: вода чиста,
>      дно піщане. Піду!» Христя спускається з гори (Панас Мирний, III, 1954,
>      242); Піщані грудочки сухо тріщать під моїми чобітьми (Петро Колесник,
>      На фронті.., 1959, 10).
> 2. Який містить у собі багато піску. На піщаних ґрунтах Полісся в міжряддя кукурудзи можна підсівати кормовий люпин (Колгоспник України,
>      4, 1958, 30); Пара конячин ледве тягли наш віз, що аж сичав по піщаній
>      дорозі (Олесь Досвітній, Вибр., 1959, 39).
> 3. Який росте, живе на піску, в пісках. Схили засівали сумішшю стоколоса безостого та еспарцету піщаного (Колгоспник України, 4,
>      1957, 15).

[Пісковий](http://sum.in.ua/s/piskovyj):

> 1. Прикм. до пісок 1. Злякана отара помчала світ за очі, і піскова хуртовина гнала її все далі... (Зінаїда Тулуб, В степу.., 1964, 72);
>      //  Який складається з піску. Цікавою у Стрілецькому степу є
>      рослинність піскових схилів, яка пов'язана з місцем виходу пісків
>      (Український ботанічний журнал, XII, 2, 1956, 53); //  Який вміщує в
>      собі багато піску. Його хатина — з решти корабля, На неї білий шум
>      прибою бризка, І в ніч осінню піскова земля Його гойдає ніжно, мов
>      колиска (Максим Рильський, I, 1956, 59).
> 2. Який діє за допомогою пересипання піску. **Пісковий годинник** вперше застосували у середні віки, тобто пізніше від водяного і сонячного
>      (Наука і життя, 12, 1960, 17).

Як бачимо слова схожі, але все ж між ними є різниця.

На рахунок "пісочного" чи то "піскового" (а якщо вірити Вікіпедії, де є стаття про "Пісковий годинник", то ще й можна сказати "піщаного") годинника - в блозі Пономарева пише:

> **Правильний варіянт - пісковий годинник**.

Хоч, [Літературне слововживання](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53407/31821.html) пише, що можливий варіант "піщаний годинник".

Давайте заглянемо ще в [Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) і звернемо увагу на слово "пісочний" - серед синонімів або кольори (жовтий, золотий, золотистий тощо) або прикметники, що означають щось розсипчасте (крихкий, ламкий тощо). Тому гадаю, що найкраще буде казати "пісочний колір", "пісочне печиво".

Коли говоримо про бурю, то краще сказати "[пилова буря](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8F)".

Але як бачимо можуть бути випадки, коли слова "піщаний" та "піщаний" можуть бути синонімами (наприклад, у значенні "який містить у собі багато піску"). Тому можна сказати і "пісочна пустеля" і "піщана пустеля" (маємо [Велику Піщану Пустелю](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D1%96%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)).

Answer (score -3):

Калька з російської, але використовується як назва тіста. Тобто у повсякденному обігу української мови його не вживають окрім цього випадку.

Comment: Чому ви вважаєте, що це калька з російської? Наприклад, у нас *молоко→молочний*, так само, як і у них. Має бути якось інакше? *молоч**а**ний*? *молоковий*?

Comment: Песочное тесто, в українській мові звучало би як пісчане тісто. Але зважаючи на те, що це зробили назвою тіста, то існує така назва тіста

Comment: Якщо ви відповідаєте комусь у коментарях, то ставте равлик "@" і за ним без пробілу ім'я того до кого ви звертаєтесь, вам одразу випаде підказка. Наприклад, `@АннаСолнцева`. Натискайте tab, щоб використати підказку.

Comment: @АннаСолнцева, є село [Пісочна](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пісочна). З 1643 року. На заході України (біля дороги Львів–Стрий). Чи та, чи якась інша Пісочна згадується у [статті «Свято проголошеня Української Републики серед У. С. С.» в журналі «Дїло» (18.12.1917)](https://zbruc.eu/node/74509), [«Споминах з часів української революції (1917–1921)» (1927–1931) Всеволода Петрова](//bit.ly/2uYdQbF), [«Поіменному списку боєвих відділів 1 полку Українських Січових Стрільців»](//bit.ly/2O9xSZB) тощо. Тож, НМД, навряд чи це росіянізм.

Comment: Іще _пісочна досвідно-меліоративна станція_ згадуєтсья у [«Збірнику узаконень та розпоряджень робітничо-селянського уряду України за 1926 рік» (1926)](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/ЗУРРСУУ/1926/1/5) (так, документ радянський, але правопис так відверто дохвилівський: _соціялістична_, _комісаріят_, _народніх/народнього_, _відповідальности_, _инші_).

Comment: Yola, до речі, може, я помиляюся, але здається, SE почав надсилати сповіщення всім учасникам обговорення в коментарях (тобто `@ім'я` вже не є критичним) — зараз і перевіримо, чи надійшло Вам сповіщеня про цей коментар?

Comment: @АннаСолнцева, дякую за відповідь. Але у нас не прийнято просто висувати думку, ні на що не посилаючись і жодним чином не аргументуючи. Якби Ви змогли довести, що це калька і що в повсякденному обігу в інших випадках не вживають (джерелами або хоча б якимись логічними міркуваннями) — то це була б інша справа.